# Method of images for infinite cylinder between two parallel surfaces, one insulating and the other constant temperature

Tags: thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction, method-of-images

Trying to solve for temperature distribution of a infinite cylinder of radius $R$ of uniform time independent heat generation [$P$] = W$\cdot$m$^{-3}$ suspended between two planes a distance $d$ apart, one being at constant temperature $T$ and the other an insulating boundary.  The medium of the cylinder and space between planes has thermal conductivity [$\kappa$] = W$\cdot$m$^{-1}$K$^{-1}$ with differential equation being $\nabla^2T=-P/k$.

Was able to use method of images for case of single constant temperature plane, by merely placing second cylinder of negative heat generation density $-P$ an equal distance below.

How would I use image method for the constant temperature/insulating surfaces cylinder sandwich?

Comment: The BC for an insulating plane is $dT/dz = 0$.

Comment: so i would place like-signed image charges on either side of insulating plane?

Comment: Are you certain that your first case of mirroring the power source on the two sides of the plane is NOT the $dT/dz$ solution, since the profiles generated are symmetrical about the plane?

Comment: mirroring opposite signs will generate constant temperature surface

Comment: So what happens when you mirror equal signs?

Comment: should set $dT/dz=0$ at the midpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mirror plane criteria to set a constant temperature is $T = \mathrm{constant}$. Setting a source on one side and an equal sink on the other can generate this.

The mirror plane criteria for an insulated surface is $dT/dz = 0$. Setting two equal sources on opposite sides can generate this.